# Hoe get the dob or date birth form string in php

Tags: php

my string is

```
Personal Details :-Name: ABHISHEK DAS-Sex : Male-Date of Birth : 21st July 1986.-Marital status: Married-Nationality: Indian-Languages I can speak: Hindi, English, Bengali. -Declaration:-I here by declare that all the details furnished above are true to the best of my knowledge.-Date:9th November 2017 Abhishek Das----
```

i want get the Date of Birth : 21st July 1986 from above string

Comment: what you have tried so far? add your attempt in your question

Comment: Where does the string come from?

Comment: There are requirements to what questions can be ask and how they should be asked. Please read a bit about that to prevent your questions from getting closed or down voted: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: @AlivetoDie that string from resume parsing i need get the personal details from that string thanks for your reply

Comment: You can aslo try this [Solution](https://3v4l.org/EbMvD)

Answer (score 1):

```
$str="
Personal Details :-Name: ABHISHEK DAS-Sex : Male-Date of Birth : 21st July 1986.-Marital status: Married-Nationality: Indian-Languages I can speak: Hindi, English, Bengali. -Declaration:-I here by declare that all the details furnished above are true to the best of my knowledge.-Date:9th November 2017 Abhishek Das----";

$date = trim(explode(".-",explode(":",$str)[4])[0]);
```

Comment: With your code it is giving result as `21st July 1986.` With adding `".-"` in your code it will gives perfect result.

Comment: Ok, have you found it usefull?

Comment: @kalaivanan Accept this as your answer if you feel it is your result.